# Uploader error in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, amazon-s3, uploader, cakephp-2.4

I was following this tutorial (http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader) for using uploader to upload images to amazon s3 and it give

```
//view
<?php echo $this->Form->create('OtherModel',array('type' => 'file')); 
echo $this->Form->input('Upload.0.upload',array('type' => 'file', 'class'=>'form-control'));
echo $this->Form->input('Upload.1.upload',array('type' => 'file', 'class'=>'form-control'));
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'),array('class'=>'btn btn-success')); ?>
```

In controller I use `$this->OtherModel->saveAssociated($this->request->data)`

```
//model Upload
    var $actsAs = array(
           'Uploader.Attachment' => array('upload' => array(
                                                                'overwrite' => false,                                                               
                                                                'transport' => array(
                                                                'class' => AttachmentBehavior::S3,
                                                                'accessKey' => '...',
                                                                'secretKey' => '...',
                                                                'bucket' => '...',
                                                                'region' => ...,
                                                                'folder' => '...',
                                                                'returnUrl' => true
                                                                                    ))));
```

It give me error below on I submit

```
Error: Call to undefined function Transit\finfo_open()  
File: C:\wamp\www\car_dealers\app\Vendor\mjohnson\transit\src\Transit\File.php  
Line: 338
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp
```

What is wrong and what should I do? Can anyone help please?

Comment: check you have finfo http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.setup.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the aboe comment and you just need to make `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` uncomment on your php.ini file.

Comment: I have the same problem but your solution was not enough can you give my question a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233228/cakephp-upload-image-can-not-determine-the-mimetype